# Using search.php without a 's' field in searchform.php

Tags: search

Sorry if this is a simple/daft question but I'm still getting to grips with how WordPress search functions.

I want to completely replace the standard search within my template with a custom search that only queries a certain custom post type and its meta fields. I have a search form which does this and search.php which returns the correct data. **However**, the search will not function unless I include a input field named 's' and it is not empty. I take it WP needs this to access search.php?

I have no need for a search field as my search is based upon custom taxonomies and meta fields. So how can I still use my search without this field?

Is this possible?

Comment: Could you just make the `s` field `<input type="hidden" />`?

Comment: I could but it still needs a value for the search to work. I dont want it in my code at all as I'm not using it and if its hidden there's nothing to stop people using dev tools to change its value.

Comment: I can understand not wanting it in your code if it's not needed, but realize there's also nothing to stop people from entering `yoursite.com?s=my+search` directly which will accomplish the same thing as modifying a form input using dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure as how to get around using `id="s"` in the input field. But just to clarify, I believe wordpress is doing something like `$input = $_POST["s"];` when the search is submitted. The `id="s`" is necessary because it tells the php script from which html input field to pull the input from. Wordpress would then do all kinds of stuff to the `$input` variable and search the site for it. Not a solution, but hopefully resolves some confusion.

Comment: You probably mean `name="s"` right? I don't think the `id` attribute matters in the `$_POST` super global.

Comment: hmm. yes, I think you are right.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you've made this hard on yourself. Without having all of the details I can't offer a working solution but I'd suggest using the `s` parameter instead of trying to get rid of it. That parameter is important, as you've noticed.

Use the parameter plus a filter on `pre_get_posts` to control the search, instead of completely hijacking it.

```
function alter_search_wpse_105761($qry) {
  if ($qry->is_search()) {
    $qry->set('post_type','your-post-type');
    // and other conditions
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','alter_search_wpse_105761');
```

There are a lot of [questions and answers here mentioning `pre_get_posts`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=pre_get_posts) so it should not be hard to work out the details, and you can edit the question with additional details to get more specific responses.